# How can I detect the rightmost line in an image

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing

I get the following output seen in the picture. I have found the biggest object in the image but I need the right line.

[image: Example]

```
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(imgGray, 100, 255, 1)
cnts = cv2.findContours(threshh.copy(), cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)
c = max(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea)
extRight = tuple(c[c[:, :, 0].argmax()][0]) # sağ taraf
cv2.circle(img, (extRight[0], extRight[1]+yx), 6, (0, 0, 255), -1)
```

Comment: how did you try to solve this?

Comment: contour method, I want to put a point according to the coordinate information by taking the most accurate credit as a reference.

Comment: but the code I type finds the thickest contour every time

Comment: and sorry i'm not good at english

Comment: The reason the thickest contour is always selected is because of the line `c = max(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea)`. Instead, try computing the centroid of each component and select the rightmost one.

Comment: The problem explanation is not clear

Comment: @yunus Temurlenk     
amacım şu ki ; sağ sarafdaki resim üzerinde işlem yapıyorum.
resimde geçen çizgileri okumaya çalışıyorum ama bana en sağdaki çizgi gerekiyor yazdığım kod ise alanı en büyük olanı buluyor buda benim işimi görmüyor

Comment: @Pascal Getreuer  Could you give me some sample code for this?

Comment: As a more rudimentary approach, you can try pooling along the vertical dimension, then find the blob that is the farthest to the right.  Pooling could mean finding the average, finding the maximum value, etc. along each column individually which will give you a 1D array.  Find the blob in this 1D array that is the farthest to the right which will then give you the width (column span) of the blob in the original image.

Answer (score 1):

Moving my comment to an answer: the reason the thickest contour is always selected is because of the line `c = max(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea)`. Instead, try computing the centroid of each component and select the rightmost one.

The centroid of a contour can be computed with the "moments()" function [as described here](https://docs.opencv.org/master/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html):

> ```
> M = cv.moments(cnt)
> cx = int(M['m10']/M['m00'])
> cy = int(M['m01']/M['m00'])
> ```

Do this computation on each contour, and select the one with the largest `cx`.